# Stream file download through RestTemplate

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, outputstream, spring-cloud-netflix

I have a large file download that is served by a RestController on one server, that I need to stream through a RestController on another server. When calling the end server directly the result streams fine. However when using RestTemplate to call this server and then write the response to an OutputStream, the response is buffered on the front server until the whole file is ready, and then streamed. Is there a way I can write the file to an OutputStream as it comes in?

At the moment my code on the front server looks similar to this

```
@ResponseBody
public void downloadResults(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, @RequestParam("id") String jobId, OutputStream stream)
        throws IOException
{
    byte[] data = restTemplate.exchange("http://localhost/getFile", HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, byte[].class, parameters).getBody();
    stream.write(data);
}
```

I've set my RestTemplate to not buffer and I've verified that this is working by checking the Request type that is used, (SimpleStreamingClientHttpRequest).
The data all comes back correct, its just only written to the stream all at once, rather than as it comes in

Comment: Not sure that using `RestTemplate` is the correct approach since it  reads the response to construct an entity - try other approaches like `HttpClient`

Comment: It needs to be a `RestTemplate` as I'm proxying the request through Zuul so need to use their `ClientHttpRequestInterceptor`'s - unless I can still use interceptors with `HttpClient`?

Comment: I have resolved my issue, instead of using `RestTemplate` I have used `HttpUrlConnection` to make a basic http request, using `EurekaClient` to retrieve the correct proxied route. Looking online it appears that @shachar is correct and RestTemplate is always going to have a buffering effect as it tries to wrap the response in `HttpEntity` and must wait for all the data to be ready

Answer (score 1):

`RestTemplate` is not meant for streaming the response body, as [pointed out in this JIRA issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-14882).

Comment: Do you have an example of how to do it with webclient?

Answer (score 1):

You can use restTemplate.execute. See https://www.baeldung.com/spring-resttemplate-download-large-file